# Using output .csv file from one python script in another

Tags: python, csv, input, output

I am currently using two different types of python scripts. One extracts data and saves it as a CSV file, and the other characterizes data. Both work perfectly separately, but I am trying to find a way to characterize the data from the outputted CSV file without having to run them separately. Importing script1 into script2 is easy, but reading the CSV file from script1 is what I can't figure out. I am going to provide the output of script1 and where I am trying to insert it in script2:

```
    # create file or append to file
    filename = '%s.csv' % gps

    if os.path.exists(filename):
     append_write = 'a' # append if already exists
   else:
     append_write = 'w' # make a new file if not

   # save file
   with open('!/usr/bin/env python/%s.csv' % gps, mode=append_write) as features_file:
features_writer = csv.writer(features_file, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

(!/usr/bin/env python has replaced the directory I am actually saving this CSV file in due to privacy reasons.)

I am trying to then place the file from this output into the following command:

```
    x_new = pd.read_csv('filename %s.csv gps' , names = attributes)
```

I have tried a variety of ways to input the script1 output into this command, but can't find the correct way to do this. Please help me out. If any further information is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This line is definitely wrong:

```
x_new = pd.read_csv('filename %s.csv gps' , names = attributes)
```

probably you mean:

```
x_new = pd.read_csv(filename , names = attributes)
```

Or

```
x_new = pd.read_csv('%s.csv' % gps , names = attributes)
```

but I don't think the `filename` part should be there either.

But don't write it to a file. You can just keep manipulating the data. And if you want to save the file anyway, you don't have to read the file, you can still just keep manipulating the array/frame you have.

also `open(filename,"w")` is all you need, if the file doesn't exist, it will be created.

Comment: this is the error that i recieve afterwards: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./TESTCC.py", line 112, in <module>
    x_new = pd.read_csv('filename %s.csv' % gps , names = attributes)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File filename 1129945218.csv does not exist: 'filename 1129945218.csv'

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what you called the file, because for some reason you put the python binary there instead of the file name. Just read it with the same name you wrote it. And don't have spaces if file names.

Answer (score -1):

You should try using [formatted strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) and putting variable directly into your file filepath (this assumes you're using Python 3+) :

```
x_new = pd.read_csv(f'{gps}.csv')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for responding. I tried this, but the error message i recieved was that 'gps' was not defined.

Comment: @LeeAnnCapistran, if your second script doesn't know about the `gps` variable that you used when saving the file then you'll have to use some other algorithm for selecting a file to load. Also, I agree with what Jonathan said in the other answer - do you really need to write to a file? Maybe just keep manipulating data: for example the first script runs and returns a dataframe and you use this df as the parameter in the second script?